# Issue with webservice accessing database

Tags: asp.net, sql-server-2008, iis

I have created a web service that accesses a database. Both the database and the webservice i.e. SQL server and IIS are on the same machine.

The problem is that when i access the webservice which in turn accesses the database on the server using my client, everything works fine.

But when i access it from other pc, i get Database error.

The same connectionstring ehich works fine while accessing the server does not open the connection while accessing the webservice remotely.

Any help appreciated.

[Edit]

When i access it on the server, i get  the logs as per my requirement like this :

ConnectionString = Server=localhost\instancename;Database=dbname;Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;

And when i access remotely, i get the logs like this :

ConnectionString = Server=localhost\instancename;Database=dbname;Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;

ERROR:

```
System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at CMACLBilling.AuthenticationService.Service1.GetUser(String userName)
   at CMACLBilling.BusinessControllers.UserBusinessController.Authenticate(String userName, String password, Int32& errorCode)
   at CMACLBilling.LoginWindow.btnLogin_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Button.OnClick()
   at System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.ButtonBase.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseLeftButtonUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.ReRaiseEventAs(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args, RoutedEvent newEvent)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.OnMouseUpThunk(Object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
   at System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs.InvokeEventHandler(Delegate genericHandler, Object genericTarget)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs.InvokeHandler(Delegate handler, Object target)
   at System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(Object target, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
   at System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(Object source, RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean reRaised)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(DependencyObject sender, RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseTrustedEvent(RoutedEventArgs args)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(RoutedEventArgs args, Boolean trusted)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessStagingArea()
   at System.Windows.Input.InputManager.ProcessInput(InputEventArgs input)
   at System.Windows.Input.InputProviderSite.ReportInput(InputReport inputReport)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.ReportInput(IntPtr hwnd, InputMode mode, Int32 timestamp, RawMouseActions actions, Int32 x, Int32 y, Int32 wheel)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndMouseInputProvider.FilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, WindowMessage msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.InputFilterMessage(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(IntPtr hwnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam, Boolean& handled)
   at MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(Object o)
   at System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(Delegate callback, Object args, Int32 numArgs)
   at MS.Internal.Threading.ExceptionFilterHelper.TryCatchWhen(Object source, Delegate method, Object args, Int32 numArgs, Delegate catchHandler)
```

Comment: specify the connection string in question, if you think it may cause the problem or the code which shown the error..

Answer (score 2):

As i guessed about your connection that you are providing wrong information:

Check your connection string:

```
ConnectionString = "Server=localhost\instancename;Database=dbname;Uid=uid;Pwd=pwd;"
```

and the error is `Error Locating Server/Instance Specified`- A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible.

**localhost** is refers to the your system on which you are working. If you access this from another computer then it will cause error.

Example as below help to configure correct connection string:

```
<connectionStrings>

<add name=”SampleConnectionString” connectionString=”Data Source=machinename\instancename;Initial Catalog=AdventureWorks;Integrated Security=SSPI;Min Pool Size=5;Max Pool Size=60;Connect Timeout=30″ providerName=”System.Data.SqlClient”/>

</connectionStrings>
```

and `Connect via an IP address of your server`

> Server=190.190.200.100,1433;Network Library=DBMSSOCN;Initial
>   Catalog=myDataBase;User ID=myUsername;Password=myPassword;

or

`Server=IISPCName` or `Server= IISPCName\InstanceName`

When i do such functionality as you do copy the computer name from my Computer properties and then the instance name.

**Check following link for solving such type of problem:**
[Resolving “A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server…”](http://www.sqlmusings.com/2009/03/11/resolving-a-network-related-or-instance-specific-error-occurred-while-establishing-a-connection-to-sql-server/)

**Note:**
You  have to check for the sql server remote access settings if above connection does not work. Check the following links to make it work:
[How to configure SQL Server 2005 to allow remote connections](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/914277)
[Remote Access Settings for SQL Server](http://www.med-sites.com/Manual/hg/StepForSQLServer/ForSQLServer.html)

Connection string reference:
[Connection strings for SQL Server 2008](http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2008)

Comment: I had used localhost because IIS and SQL server will always remain on the same machine; And databse is being accessed by the webservice, should localhost work or not?

Comment: try to use windows authentication `connectionString="Initial Catalog=MyDb;Data Source=MyServer;Integrated Security=SSPI;"`